# Price of e-beam evaporator

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, production-technology

I'm trying to find an accurate price estimate for an electron beam evaporator for a research project. The intended application is for use in large-scale manufacturing.

How does one usually go about finding this information? Are there any recommended reliable resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get this information on the internet easily since these are costly machines which are not typically bought off amazon.
The best way to get this information is to ask a manufacturer (eg Kurt Lesker, CHA etc) for a quote. They will ask your application and recommend devices which will suite you.
You can expect them to cost from a few hundred thousand USD to about a million USD.